# How to set equivilent of android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" in Adobe AIR for mobile

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

I have an Adobe AIR Actionscript for Mobile project. I want to publish so that it behaves like: sensorLandscape "Landscape orientation, but can be either normal or reverse landscape based on the device sensor." - from [Android API documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

I have set:

```
<initialWindow>
    <content>AppName.swf</content>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
    <autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
<initialWindow>
```

in the App.xml.

The result is on a Nexus 7 when publishing a debug file from FlashBuilder 7 - is that it is always landscape - but it does not re-orient with the device to show reverse landscape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you haven't give any code so I asssume that you do not listen to:

```
stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGE, orientationChangeListener, false, 0, true);
//...
protected function orientationChangeListener(event:Event):void
    {
        /*
        log("beforeOrientation:" + event["beforeOrientation"].toString()
             + "\nafterOrientation:" + event["afterOrientation"].toString());
        */
    }
```

Android on orientation change creates new instance of the view, AIR doesn't so you have to program this by listening to orientation change and act accordingly e.g. by rotating your view (and resizing etc.) also check for the resize event on stage as it seems to respond quicker to screen orientation change.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onStageResized, false, 0, true);
//...
protected function onStageResized(e:Event=null):void
{
    trace("sr.Orientation: " + stage.deviceOrientation);
}
```

best regards

Comment: Thanks. I was listening to resize. It turns out that I didn't have auto rotate set on my Android devices. As soon as I turned it on - it was all working. However, I believe that with sensorLandscape it does work. In the captive runtime AIR app it does not fire a resize event or the ORIENTATION_CHANGE event when I rotate the device when the global auto rotate setting is locked. Does anyone know of a way around this?